# Как сделать систему пати в роблокс

Tags: lua, roblox

я хочу сделать систему пати в игре, ее то я сделаю, но часть с телепортацией для меня сложна, вот есть у нас таблица с именами игроков в пати

```
{"Plr1", "Plr2"}
```

Теперь нужно чтобы эти два игрока телепортировались на один и тот же сервер, вместе